# Opening file for reading in COBOL

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm using [OpenCobolIDE](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/) 4.7.4 (it's based on GnuCOBOL) on Windows 10 and trying to compile this program opening a file for reading:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
      INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
         FILE-CONTROL.
         SELECT STUDENT ASSIGN TO 'input.txt'
         ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.            

   DATA DIVISION.
      FILE SECTION.
      FD STUDENT.
      01 STUDENT-FILE.
         05 STUDENT-ID PIC 9(5).
         05 NAME PIC A(25).

      WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
      01 WS-STUDENT.
         05 WS-STUDENT-ID PIC 9(5).
         05 WS-NAME PIC A(25).
      01 WS-EOF PIC A(1). 

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      OPEN INPUT STUDENT.
         PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF='Y'
         READ STUDENT INTO WS-STUDENT
            AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF
            NOT AT END DISPLAY WS-STUDENT
         END-READ
         END-PERFORM.
      CLOSE STUDENT.
   STOP RUN.
```

The *input.txt* is in the same directory as the source coude, yet I'm still getting the following error:

```
Main.cob:24: libcob: File does not exist (STATUS = 35) File : 'input.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most IDE for other languages happen to run the executable from another directory (where it is built for example).

A simple test is to write a test program, opening a file for writing. 
You'll quickly see what happens.

Comment: You were right, this IDE puts executables in bin directory of the current user.

Answer (score 5):

OCIDE has a setting for the output directory, the default is "bin" (relative to the source file). Effectively it just passes this setting to the compiler `cobc source.cob -o bin\source.exe`

You can change this behaviour in settings [Menu Preferences -> Compiler](http://opencobolide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#compiler-settings):

> **Output directory**
>
> This option let you chose where to put the binaries, by default binaries will be placed into a bin folder next to the source file. You can define another relative or absolute directory if you want.

In any case you can set the actual name in the environment, check [GC FAQ - How to map a file name to an external name](http://open-cobol.sourceforge.net/faq/#assign).

As an alternative you can set the data directory with the environment var `COB_FILE_PATH`.

Both environment options can be set in settings [Menu Preferences -> Run](http://opencobolide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#environment).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps better will be to write the full path in the select clause.

```
select STUDENT ASSIGN TO '/xpto/folder1/input.txt'
```

Comment: Perhaps not, because then you have a locked set-up for the program. At least make things relative.